# Pass a parameter to function with quotation marks

Tags: bash, function, parameters, alias

I am trying to create a function in my .bashrc which allows calling a command with a parameter.

Original command:

```
openWindow —comment “medium”
```

What I’m trying to achieve in bashrc:

```
openWindow(){openWindow —comment “$1”;}
```

So instead of typing the whole thing, this should do the same thing:
openWindow medium

When running in terminal the function is not recognised. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need more whitespace. `{` and `}` are not special characters, just reserved *words*. `{openWindow` is not two words `{` and `openWindow`, just like `ab` is not two words `a` and `b`.

```
openWindow () { command openWindow --comment "$1"; }
```

(Also, be sure you are using regular ASCII quotes `"`, not the typographic quotes `“` and `”` that appear in your question.)

Comment: Won't this result in an infinite loop?

Comment: Yup; I just added whitespace to the copy-paste, so didn't notice the names were the same. The `command` built-in used in my update ensures that the actual command `openWindow` is run, rather than recursively calling the function.